# I hate broccoli!

Tags: code-golf

My mom really wants me to eat broccoli, but I hate it and never want to eat it. Mom wants to trick me so she cuts it into small pieces, puts it in a salad and mixes it. Help me find out if the salad contains broccoli!

**Input:**

Array of mixed letters of all the ingredients. For a single broccoli ingredient it could be:

```
[c,o,r,b,l,c,i,o]
```

**Output:**

Boolean or other convienient output allowing to distinguish if a salad contains broccoli or not.

**Rules:**

- all possible ingredients are `onion`, `broccoli`, `celery` and `beans`
- input array is always formed of mixing valid ingredients (meaning that it can be always decoded back to the original ingredients array)
- input array cannot be decoded into more than one valid ingredient combination
- each ingredient can occur 0 or more times in the salad

**Sample test cases:**

`true` stands for a salad with broccoli

```
[c,o,r,b,l,c,i,o] //true
[o,b,n,o,i,i,e,l,n,a,o,r,n,s,b,o,c,c] //true
[l,c,b,r,r,o,r,c,i,i,c,o,c,b,o,c,c,b,i,o,l,o,l,o] //true

[] //false
[o,n,i,o,n] //false
[b,n,s,i,a,o,n,b,a,s,e,e,n,o,n] //false
[b,r,o,c,c,o,l,i,e,y,e,r,l,a,e,e,n,s,y] //false
[e,n,s,o,e,n,i,o,a,o,o,e,n,n,e,l,n,l,e,o,e,r,c,l,o,y,i,r,y,r,y,b,e,l,n,n,c,c,r,c,e,y,i,e] //false
```

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins!**

Comment: Can we take the input as a string instead of array?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes

Comment: Poor broccoli! I haven't heard anyone who wants to eat it.

Comment: This challenge would have been much more interesting with soya.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft with soya you would still have `count(c) > count(l)`. However I will probably put an adjusted version in the future ;)

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Broccoli with ranch :)

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Great, now I feel like I'm weird for liking broccoli /:

Comment: This problem is a subset of [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/201685/75323); @RedwolfPrograms I also love broccoli, once I even [wrote about broccoli on my math blog](http://mathspp.blogspot.com/2019/04/pocket-maths-mathy-broccoli.html)

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Broccoli is the _only_ green vegetable my kid likes.

Comment: Wow, I adore broccoli. It's literally my favourite vegetable. People are strange.

Answer (score 39):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @dingledooper

```python
lambda a:cmp(*map(a.count,'bs'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLDoMgELz7Fd7QxvTQYxO/pO0BKKYkuhi0B7/eoh3iQlOTCexjZnZxXOaXo8vatfe1l4N6ylJe9TBWp0GOlTxr96a5EWoSdb2O3tJcdtVNaNEIF@ADVEAfsOXsnn/UxdHq0EKgWMCAtuUlk9viCRwHWZ1KRjcFimd0zSw0k0jlvrFFrk/OYAUv0W6fKA7rn82IyVA6pWLLWLYkwV2iZgD6L@Oz4eOw8R0XnB55mclOe08iy0uOtcZl4rS8Rtlv6xE7Zq/Zey7Q87jHU2U6xFaLGobxTRh9/QA)

Returns `1` for true, `0` for false

Answer (score 17):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
[:=/1#.'cy'=/]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xCgJBDER7vyJosQh6antwlWBlZSsWuyFiZMlArtqvPyNi4UkIITMvQ57Tskt3GnpKtKE99dHbjo6X82m69sPusOoStzTsbtN6IfxA@APdKTG8VFYk@pFRDKpSLcNtLGCeAZWLO5xVGfz2i6JGfbHDB5utMIXNtGKjZljJo4j9ux7ZqCpNvOYgxjYjQoJEbkYMi5erQJwrmnrzVkIxZmdpKnE6vQA)

*Idea of invariant based on letter counts from mathjunkie's [clever answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204690/15469) -- be sure to upvote him.*

- 0 for contains broccoli
- 1 for not

Tests if the number `c`s is equal to the number of `y`s.  This will only be true when no broccoli is present.

Answer (score 16):

## perl -ple, 14 bytes

```
$_=y-y---y-c--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxCsBACAT7e0day5R5S8iJhSDu4aXx8zEWywwDuyTsrDruKymJekxUNQPMMB2MmMaKMeXxPeAKH@Ib0vag4WJuAgk2pEZGzi7OHCyp8mG9/dlFtn4)

Prints 0 if no broccoli is present, something else if there is.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: It counts the number of `y`s in the string, and subtracts the number of `c`s. If equal, no broccoli is present. Adding spaces to the code, it reads `$_ = y-y-- - y-c--`. Using more traditional delimiters, and using the usual name for the operator, this becomes `$_ = tr/y// - tr/c//`. `tr/y//` replaces any `y` in `$_` by, well, itself, because the replacement part is empty. But it returns the number of `y`s replaced, hence, counting the number of `y`s. `tr/c//` does the same, but for `c`s.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„bsS¢Ë
```

-1 byte by reversing the output: will output `0` if it contains broccoli and `1` if not.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8pOLgQ4sOd///n5pXnJ@al5mfmA@k8lJz8nJS81OLknPyKzOLKosqk4AiecnJRcmplZmpAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Jc2xCcNQDATQVYxq7@AhUoYUX0KFQOhAHwK/S5UmTcgAKTJKvIkXcWSCioPHHUJvbLpfx/pcaNrur4mWfbu9uZ@@n/Wxz/uZBMkuBpoJHDBTj4aMzhApdOFMpJgJ5DA2eB3NEx2bMEQlR7eG4NZV4y9ZZbjp0PRW2kdpBbQ2DRVRv1yhKY5hOXJwSYik6DClyw8).

**6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** alternative which outputs `1` if it contains broccoli and `0` if not:

```
AS¢üÊн
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fMfjQosN7Dndd2Pv/f2pecX5qXmZ@Yj6QykvNyctJzU8tSs7Jr8wsqiyqTAKK5CUnFyWnVmamAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Jc3BCQJRDATQVpactwexBo/i4SfkEAgZyAfhN@DBk1iCdejFbcAabGTNIjkMPGYIemPT9TyW246m7@U@0W7dH96P5blcP691Xo8kSHYx0EzggJl6NGR0hkihC2cixUwgm7HB62ieaNuEISo5ujUEt64af8kqw02HprfSPkoroLVpqIj65QpNcQzLkYNLQiRFhymdfg).

**Explanation:**

```python
„bs     # Push string "bs"
   S    # Convert it to a character-list: ["b","s"]
    ¢   # Count each in the (implicit) input
     Ë  # Check if the counts are the same for both letters (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
        # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

A       # Push the lowercase alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 S      # Convert it to a character-list: ["a","b","c",...,"z"]
  ¢     # Count each in the (implicit) input-list
   ü    # For each overlapping pair of counts:
    Ê   #  Check that they are not equal to one another (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
     н  # Pop and only leave the first check (for letters 'a' and 'b')
        # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

If the amount of `b` and `s`/`a` are the same, it means the input only contains `beans` and no `broccoli`.

Comment: Wasn’t an input that includes broccoli, but other invalid salad ingredients supposed to be false? Or did I read that wrong?

Comment: @brandonscript You've indeed read that correct, but the challenge also states "_Boolean **or other convienient output allowing to distinguish if a salad contains broccoli or not**._" So in my top program I output `0` for truthy and `1` for falsey (which is probably why you're your questions is coming from?), and in my bottom answer I output `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey. So `broccolieyerlaeensy` for example (which contains `broccoli` as well as some other ingredients) would output `1` in my top program and `0` in my bottom program as falsey result.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 26 bytes

```matlab
@(b)b&&diff(sum(b'=='cl'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsJADEX3nsKNTrvpDQpeZRIzEIj5kFFhTl8jgljJIuG95BPwvT5la@uyLNtlopnO56u2NvXHbaKyroWtzPPWpsIIMlaU@Xi6x0MOyUAOVTGvCO8E5l9rTBEIVmXwW5LCsn533nOr1j9xrvAdIe9a4VS7iP@7yEiYypCwmr6PnU8AycSKbJ5PmkCCDUNjxKAkzhwsQ@V7uL0A)

Credit to @mathjunkie's answer for the idea. Interestingly comparing `c` and `l` counts also works because `celery` has one of each, but `broccoli` has a different number.

MATLAB likes to expand `==` into 2D arrays if the inputs are vectors in differing orientations. However this doesn't work with empty arrays. Fortunately empty is false in MATLAB and non-empty with any non-zero elements is true, so we can simply use the input as a logical true-false to capture that case.

Comment: Have you tried MATL?

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>19</s></sup> 12 bytes

```apl
>/+/↑'cl'=⊂⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v/fTl9b/1HbRPXkHHXbR11Nj3rn/f@fVJSfnJyfkwkA)

Note that you have to add `⎕←` to the beginning for it to output. Originally created with **ngn/apl**.

```apl
>/+/↑'cl'=⊂⍞
            ⍞ ⍝ get input
     'cl'=⊂   ⍝ make two packed vectors: characters equal to c and l
  +/↑         ⍝ turn into two row matrix and add (to get number of 'c's and 'l's
>/            ⍝ Are there more 'c's than 'l's?
```

returns broccoli: 1, no broccoli: 0

Comment: [Turning this into a dfn](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/WkNbXz1J3fZR71bNR51LgZxiMKf2f9qjtgmPevsedTU/6l3zqHfLofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cpqCcV5Scn5@dkplamFuUkpqbmFVeqAwA) yields the same bytecount...

Comment: Can you do something like [I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204708/69200) am doing in terms of checking `l` and `c` equality and only summing once?

Comment: @streetster I wish I knew how. APL is similar to K but using what you did would cause a length error. I tried to do it with something like ∊(is ⍺ in ⍵) but that can't find the *number of times* that ⍺ is in ⍵.

Comment: @Λ̸̸ that outputs, but what is it supposed to output? It outputs `1` for `''broccolieyerlaeensy'` *and* `'broccoli'`.

Comment: @streetster I managed (with the help of APL Orchard). I needed to add ⊂ but it worked and since I only use input once, I don't need to assign L. Saved 7 bytes.

Comment: Nice golfing! [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) is fairly inspired by APL, and I am normally out-golfed by APL solutions!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>33</s>  32 bytes

*Saved 1 byte by not forcing a Boolean value, as suggested by @SteveBennett*

Takes a string and returns *undefined* (falsy) for a broccoli-free salad (yummy!) or a string (truthy) otherwise (yuck!).

```javascript
s=>s.split`b`[s.split`s`.length]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BTkNBCEX3foW71y58f1B/pDZ5A9IWQ7gNjDXz9c@p0USTsWEBuRxyL2/lWpJDL/XJ8Srrcbfm7jnnvJjWhZb9z5jLbOKnej6sDE@YzIbTZtp/aD0/UoAZpodp@/B7fdxMjCBjxbT9d3UHATlUxbwgPKm7DCBjikCwKoNvDCms1w39w04v/pUX7/Ve5FEOV/hAJ08tcCop4mPi20eahJVOZRtQXYZ0j4LevP9rAgk2NI0WjbrizMHSVPr5@gk)

Comment: Surely that succeeds for `[l,c,b,r,r,o,r,c,i,i,c,o,c,b,o,c,c,b,i,o,l,o,l,o]` by chance that this is a triple broccoli salad, and that wouldn't have worked for a double broccoli salad?

Comment: @Neil Yes, I was just (slowly) figuring it out. :-( Now fixed.

Comment: Is the `!` really required? The problem isn't strict on the output,  so you would just be returning truthy for broccoli, or falsy (undefined) without.

Comment: @SteveBennett I guess you're right. Thank you!

Comment: Btw I really love this double `split` solution. So elegant.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 32 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>++this[c],r=y=0)|r>y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9hbsMgDIX/9xT7CauX7AJkB0mjhTDSsVET4WwS0u6eGTdaK03IAfw@v0c@7Lcll8OyPtES3ny@JPz0ZZvNRqaj5mIX5Ux3PK7vgXo3QDbFPOuf3JXNJaQUfRPTWY2H3kGCDBNEcBAgDQ9tu@Yvf@gTN5HFwMuzjGAFRSBWEuPuBtfpicUsiJMhJ9CO8s7ubCP1N3jo63G2kSQRBcK73iR5QbKRTSzfPC/8x@U9qAbUFxeuzGe78wTljr92kig1s/pfb7j/beQ9iYeTZxfmMn9rTTuDklgJL7q/JYxN9ku0zqv21Kvm8UWfhvYM6hVIm25W1NASwzrCqLXefgE)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>n+=~~{r:1,y:-1}[c],n=0)|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/RTsMwDEXf@xXsLQGvZa@TUj6kq2hqsqkoc6qkIFXAfr04XsUmochN4nt8b/puP23COIzTlsKbW45mSaZO5dmOCk1NT@Zy@Yr7Hcz77e6nwRbIPOtvWjBQCt6VPpxUVzQIASL04AFhgNA@VNUUP1zRBG4SiwMvxzKBFZQgsRIYxxucp3sWoyAoQyjQivLO7mwj9TdYNPl4tD5JIglEd71e8gbJJjaxfHO86B8X16AckF88c0U@25VPMN/x104QJWdm/@uN1r/1vAfxQHn2zFzkb65@ZUgSM@FEd7eEroxu9Badqg6NKh9f9KGtTqBeIWlTbzZHlco0@mHqoNNaL78)

Comment: I think there might be a similar formula that works with < and > instead of ==, but I haven't checked

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes it saves a byte, but should not be two

Comment: For anyone else mystified by this like I was: `++this[foo]` is the same as `++foo` but doesn't throw if `foo` isn't defined. `r` and `y` are just being set to zero in a convenient location - the fact that they're passed to `map` is conveniently irrelevant. Overall the code is just counting if there are more `r`s than `y`s

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
›№θb№θs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO9KDWxJLVIwzm/FMgr1FFQSlLS1FFAcIuVNDU1rf//j87XSdLJ08nXyQTCVJ0cIDsRyCsC0sVAmXydZJ3k2P@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean; `-` for broccoli, nothing for none. Explanation:

```
 №θb    Number of `b`s in input
›       Exceeeds
    №θs Number of `s`s in input
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 11 bytes

**Solution:**

```
</+/"sb"=/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1BCsNACAXQu7hpSynZp@1hRjEgET84K08/NRQXH55@PF841zr2z/bcaDJ9t30dtzsJkl0M9CZwwEw9BjImQ6TRhTORYiaQy9jgPb26KmGITo5pA8FjqsZfsm/hpqXpo3VWawe0OwMd0a9coSmOsqwsbgmRFC1Teqwf)

**Explanation:**

Shamelessly stolen "more s' than b's" logic from [mathjunkie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204690/69200):

```
</+/"sb"=/: / the solution
    "sb"=/: / "sb" equal (=) each-right (/:)
  +/        / sum
</          / s less than b? (aka no brocoli?)
```

Comment: You beat me by one because you have each-right. Is that in APL?  Also just realized that my new code is very similar to your code (I didn't try to copy).

Answer (score 4):

## Zsh, 22 characters

```sh
((${#1//a}==${#1//b}))
```

Expects the ingredients as a single command line parameter.
Sets the exit code to 1 for broccoli alert and 0 for no broccoli.

(Just to keep the exit code semantics of 0 = Ok / non-0 = error. Using `<` for comparison would save 1 character but reverse the result's encoding.)

Sample run:

```
manatwork@manatwork ~ % . ./broccoli-detector.zsh obnoiielnaornsbocc
manatwork@manatwork ~ % echo $?
1
manatwork@manatwork ~ % . ./broccoli-detector.zsh broccolieyerlaeensy
manatwork@manatwork ~ % echo $?                                      
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fQ0OlWtlQXz@x1tYWwkqq1dT8//9/flJefmZmak5eYn5RXnFSfnIyAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##XZCxagMxDIbn3FOI5IKTIYRCu7SEDJ36DllsndIKjFSkW9ySZ7/qSEhp8SDpsz9@oy//mD6NZTxDWj8@OTzD2k@SIL3Ju9HAJKPH9KoyZhaHYoqoleGYuu6sBnx/Fy0kVCsVWcPRIspMVbKaeAkvYMVipobMqDizwlrjxNWsCOscXsQ5q5TsRHIlt1xqZDUH9RY0ilI4WaNIRFVSMqza2Jq1EkQQDakxpRcYtFs4jbDbwbL//fhy2mz679XDfp8vh8O1K5ftdlr8X80wr@aPCv2xG1Ro@gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ċⱮ⁾abE
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields `0` if the salad contains broccoli and `1` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON6x417ktMcv3//796al5xfmpeZn5iPpDKS83Jy0nNTy1KzsmvzCyqLKpMAorkJScXJadWZqaqAwA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##Lc2xDYJBCAXg/l/kGtdwCmNxEAoM4SVcdaU2Fq5iTFzARie5RU7OGIpHPiCcxKzP@bmN52OcX5X2830dl/uch8IIMlaUbVdADlUxrwhvBOalxhSBYFUGLySFZa3Z78oVvhryphVOtYn4nyL3YSpdwmpy64szIXlWkeH50AQSbOgaPTqlOHOwdJWyHb8).

#### How?

Tests whether the number of `'b'`s (in both 'broccoli' & 'beans') is equal to the number of `'a'`s (in only 'beans').

```
ċⱮ⁾abE - Link: list
 Ɱ     - map across...
  ⁾ab  - ...what: list of characters = ['a', 'b']
ċ      - ...applying: count
     E - all equal?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 18 bytes

```
+`[^bs]|bs|sb

1`b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BCsQgDEX3vcfAwGQzp5hDSIcacSGUCDqbQu/u/PxKkWiS//JNy79icTyen228tvDVvp7az67L8t50jJCkShOVXZIUqesSKipDt@Bk9E0iGZMOpYJLoJxXdBu1RDpRnQxe@GGegQlaG5uGXGlYaG6AI6qMY7feppEb@CoHoiGPk@tygLuyyo57u99V2Vx/x1s5m7jOAa7h9tDJGH9yIlPP6x8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
+`[^bs]|bs|sb
```

Delete everything that's not a `b` or an `s`, plus any remaining `bs` or `sb` pairs that result from bean salad.

```
1`b
```

Check whether there is any broccoli.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 41 bytes

```java
s->s.reduce(0,(a,c)->c<98?a-1:c<99?a+1:a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU@xTgMxDN37FValSnfQnugGLRSxIDEwlQ0xOG6uuKTxyc5VOiG@PeQKC0JRYvu952fngCdcHHYfmY@daIJDqZs@cWjaPlJiic3FevKPtKQejyNFAc3gGTnC5wSg611gAkuYSjgJ7@BYuGqblOP@9Q1Q91afpQAv8hTT4@@c25Jvz7YbaOEu22JjjfpdT766mlc4p3qxodub63tcLFclubnHy@UK67w@m7Wi1QkVkre0@jMGYDtY8sdG@tR0ZY/UVtOZrWBmszidnzvm0DbYdWF4sLJHNUINvaNaVdebq/pnxNdkvF85k6gLxJLFRWH2IaJoNCdEOZBTFSVmEhoRxxLKyRLLL7OLxijRoXkfx1qLRAL7wWvAgtmQyyO@qFFKiMU9ePFKQQbWQQdXkEik5Af23w)

Uses a `chars()`-Stream as input, returns any strictly positive value if it contains brocoli.

### Credits

- -5 bytes thanks to [Elgirhath](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94596/elgirhath) by comparing `b` to `a` instead of `b` to `s`, and by allowing any positive value instead of a strict boolean.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVDBagIxEL37FYMg7LZr0FtdrZ57KBQ8lh4mY9aOjRmZZIWl@O1p1p5KCZmXee/NS8gJrzg/Hb4yny@iCU6lN31ib7o@UGIJ5mE9@SfGpA7Po0QeY4RX5ADfE4BLbz0TxISpwFX4AOeiVfukHI7vH4B6jPXdCvCm7sCEyW1eQtrfI7fQwXOO8200RezJVYumwobq@ZY2q6cdzpdtOax2@Lhssd4u8voe1YlWV1RILqb2zyUA@yEmdzbSJ3Mpr0hdNZ3FFmZxFqbNfaKBzoxYjcXQJ2qs6rr@jb5Nxn3LmUStJ5YsNgiz8wFFQ7RClD1ZVVFiJqGRsSy@rCyh/GG2ITJKsBidC2OvxSKe3eDUY@HikEsRV9woBUJJ906ckpeBddDBFiYQKbmB3Q8). Also you probably don't need last `>0` if you specify what given output means ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [asm2bf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Asm2bf), 73 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VPRasMwDPygm/cFQj8i/NAYBmGlgUC/P5NsxZHdhw72NqUQRz7rTqd62W/r4@tZvo8DDGFmEOlPV8mWlLLmRBfQd8okNW3AZEDdFt0ylFBiSVkhF9rS@qJ6Ar2gVICdFfv8YK44FUDQsJNQMbZ2hp7lFl7V42QMgbBdsSq8ZfMIFIoxVkkZgcEqdUDnl4nQ9I5FBgJzqLeASUPt4xThDBKqp0G7eQBWvxl0yqkuajTL3DO3snlpLeR/biLorybicgRexS9H@0M2p@WqJVfzv@oudtCy@c0tCbfQ2TDNCfwqdbRmHmy4wHgZZWJ7usqpG@lzPVmGfuFjIvfo822H0VP9yMdxL8u@b3tZ17KVZStlWbe7Pj8)

Takes input on stdin as a string; outputs either `ASCII(0x00)` or `ASCII(0x01)`.

```
@l
in r1
ceqr1,.b
cadr2,1
ceqr1,.s
cadr3,1
jnzr1,1
gt r2,r3
outr2
```

Commented code:

```
; Essentially, our game plan is to compare amount of `b' and `s' occurences.
; Start a new label
@loop
; Read a character from stdin, put it in r1.
  in r1
; If r1 = 'b' (note the way of expressing a character constant), set
; the condition flag.
  ceq r1,.b
; If the condition flag is set, add 1 to r2
  cadd r2,1
; If r1 = 's', set the condition flag. Otherwise, clear it.
  ceq r1,.s
; If the condition flag is set, add 1 to r3
  cadd r3,1
; If r1 is bigger than zero, we didn't hit eof yet, so continue reading.
; Note: The golfed version is based on a certain property beyond explaining.
; It's related to the way how labels work under the hood.
  jnz r1,%l
; The loop finished.
; Compare r2 and r3 (the accumulators).
gt r2,r3
; Display the result
out r2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string with reversed output.

```
èÕ¶Uèc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=6NW2Vehj&footer=IVU&input=WyJjb3JibGNpbyIsIm9ibm9paWVsbmFvcm5zYm9jYyIsImxjYnJyb3JjaWljb2Nib2NjYmlvbG9sbyIsICIiLCJvbmlvbiIsImJuc2lhb25iYXNlZW5vbiIsImJyb2Njb2xpZXllcmxhZWVuc3kiLCJlbnNvZW5pb2Fvb2VubmVsbmxlb2VyY2xveWlyeXJ5YmVsbm5jY3JjZXlpZSJdLW1S) - includes all test cases, footer negates the output for easier testing

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>57</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>53</s></sup> 52 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)!!!

Saved a byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
a;f(char*s){for(a=0;*s;++s)a+=*s-99?*s>120:-1;a=!a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHBTsMwDL3vK0KkSU27ahu3ETo@hO2QmBQshRg55VCmfntxu3EAFedgx372k5@hfgUYR2fbAt4cl9lcWuLCNTtbZltV2biqKXN9ODyV@bi/3z3Ue@uaO2eH8d1hKoy6rJTY3K26kLv8fFaNumgg9hGQ9EZty44/Q7mdkZNp8okQQ0yOOGVPAIuwCJ6ZGBCBYEJ5pChvETwnWxfzb6aElJZLPmV0lLzLIaR/QSy0FDH0gaMTYO6XgVKhIGSOxCVZLQYKDJF65J57L5kEwBB6DPrPgMHObpIeU6dQBNxZcY8q41egtpiFNdvbbxbbyHnwR/7JPlh620Kf9DqftKqPav1ykq2uR8Hz5jZGQmOuhMNqGL8B)

Takes a string as input and returns a \$1\$ for edible and a \$0\$ for *grossing me out*!

Comment: You don't need to initalize `a` and `b` to zero so long as they are equal

Comment: but better is save a variable using ++ and --

Comment: @l4m2 Have to init them or they'd be set to however they were left last run. But using one variable is better anyway - thanks! :-)

Comment: @l4m2 Ah, could set one to the other! Clever except could overflow to a negative after many runs.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVHBTsMwDL3vK0KkSU27ahu3ETo@hO2QmBQshRg55VCmfntxu3EAFedgx372k5@hfgUYR2fbAt4cl9lcWuLCNTtbZltV2biqKXN9ODyV@bi/3z3Ue@uaO2eH8d1hKoy6rJTY3K26kLv8fFaNumgg9hGQ9EZty44/Q7mdkZNp8okQQ0yOOGVPAIuwCJ6ZGBCBYEJ5pChvETwnWxfzb6aElJZLPmV0lLzLIaR/QSy0FDH0gaMTYO6XgVKhIGSOxCVZLQYKDJF65J57L5kEwBB6DPrPgMHObpIeU6dQBNxZcY8q41egtpiFNdvbbxbbyHnwR/7JPlh620Kf9DqftKqPav1ykq2uR8Hz5jZGQmOuhMNqGL8B) by counting `c` vs `y` instead. The result is inverted.

Comment: @Arnauld Swapping `==` for a `<`, nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 39 bytes

```cs
i=>i.Count(x=>x==98)>i.Count(x=>x=='s')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNSsQwED7bpxh62Qa6ix4EpbaXBU/ePYiHZJjVgTADk65uWfbiM/iEvkhNEIWq5DDJ95fhw7TGxPPtXvAmjcby1EJQjQPsoJ@5H3iz1b2MzaEfDn1/feV@Iau0cnNXvXiDkdKYoAehV3h4hGN11tSoFiKy1i2MtifXFlCDKDNF8WqSgiIu6IjBTA2ZUbGwgTXmsxDlx87H9J0orLKEgiT2KsEnIvlDWo7VyDSRRZ8FaVoKMqKUQ73mIXnVSEqGUSe2yaaQEUE0pInpx1mdumqr2Rlpc2880h0LNTXkLgE@3t9yGUY41q6rdmrk8RmaUlzDLaADlq8KXZWr@yfneN6uL08lCI4X5Vo@btgVc1ed5k8)

Comment: -2 by comparing `b` and `a` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNSsQwED7bpxh62Qa6ix4EpbaXBU/ePYiHZJjVgTADk65uWfbiM/iEvkhNEIWq5DDJ95fhw7TGxPPtXvAmjcby1EJQjQPsoJ@5H3iz1b2MzaEfDn1/feV@Iau0cnNXvXiDkdKYoAehV3h4hGN11tSoFiKy1i2MtifXFlCDKDNF8WqSgiIu6IjBTA2ZUbGwgTXmsxDlx87H9J0orLKEgiT2KsEnIvlDWo7VyDSRRZ8FaVoKMqKUQ73mIXnVSEqGUSe2yaaQEUE0pInpx1mdumqr2Rlpc2880h0LNTXkLgE@3t9yGUY41q6rdmrk8RmaUlzDLaADlq8KXZWr@yfneN6uL08lCI4X5Vo@btgVc1ed5k8)

Comment: 29 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC9SgNBEK69pxiuuoNLSArB5HJJIVjZWViIxe4w0YF1BmY3miOk8Rl8Ql/k3EMUDmWL2fn@dvkwzjDycHMQ3MRkLE8NsKQt7KEbuNvy/O7wUh277XGzutrNlus8V7vlelEPbfHqDBLFFKEDoTd4eIRTcVGVqOYDspYNJDtQ3YygelFmCuLUJHpFnNABvZkaMqPiyHrWkM9ElJe9C/EnUVhlCnmJ7FS8i0Tyh7Qcq4GpJwsuC2I/FWREKYc6zUPyVwMpGQbt2XrrfUYE0ZB6pl9ncW6La83OQPN740S3LFSVkBsE@Px4z2UYYSrrttirkcNnqMbiKm4A61z2d4V1kav7J@e0aGaX5zEITsvxOj5ccT2a2@I8fAE). Outputs 0 for no broccoli and positive integer otherwise

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZCxTsMwEIZn8hSnTAlKqxapQ0lTBiQmNgYGxGCfrnCSuZPOKTSquvAMPCEvEmwhkCKQB9v/f/9v68M4w8jjzV5wE3tjeWqApd/CDrqRuy3P7/Yv1aHbHjbr9dXh/GK2XK8uF/XYFq/OoKfYR@hA6A0eHuFYnFUlqvmArGUDve2pbrKoXpSZgjg1iV4RJ3ZAb6aGzKiYXc8a0poMpcvOhfjTKKwylbxEdireRSL5Y1qq1cA0kAWXBuIwHUiKUip1mjZJXw2kZBh0YBts8EkRREMamH6TxaktrjUlA83vjXu6ZaGqhMQP4PPjPcEwwr6s22KnRg6focrgKm4A64T6G2FdJHT/9BwXzWx1ykVwXOZjfrjiOofb4jR@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Elgirhath

```php
$b=count_chars($a,1);echo+($b[98]>$b[97]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dSsRADEbvfYqyFLpFEbxSqasPootMQpYGhnwls3sxiM9eUwQVmZmLwMnJ3zIv69PLMi/d6WJ8Vlh32vdp/Fh7OjAudn7nOXkJdnM3TsIzrvc9vT4@HJ@3cH8cp/XzauNRODCcMiuGsbvtdm@2m35SIIOqZEtwKwTmhpSZ3OGsyuDNIUWO/0f9dofD9oZ/NDq0Jluc1eBkRROMUhGxtuGxArJKFc8prFIbVmBIzEiIYHFhFohzRlWvXimIMTtLVfktX78A)

Comment: great answer! I don't really know PHP but it seems that you can change `!=` to `<` and `115` ('s') to `97` ('a') for -2 bytes ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

<sup>*Saved 1 byte thanks to Steve Bennett*</sup>

```
=CountIf(A:A,"b")>CountIf(A:A,"s"
```

Input is in column `A`. When you exit the cell, Sheets will automatically add the trailing parentheses.

There's nothing really clever about this solution besides implementing the concept from others.

[image]

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `<>` with `>`. It will never be less than.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 46 characters

Shortening Yaraslav's answer:

```
s=>(q=z=>s.filter(e=>e==z).length)('b')>q('s')
```

### Javascript, 62 characters

```
x=>([,a,b]=/(a*)(b*)/.exec(x.sort().join``),b.length>a.length)
```

Maybe I missed something? Just counts if there are more `b` than `a`.

Comment: Cool!!! Nice code!

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.filter(e=>e=='b').map(Date)>s.filter(e=>e=='s').map(Date)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZAxTgQxDEX7PQVdkoK5AMpWXCQxHjAy/iMngHL6IUgUi1Y7IBeW/J/tb7@Wj9LIZev3hife17y3fG7LKtrZI@cz5xxqSMtb2eJj6Zyu1Hap7gRrUF4UzzF8Sn@5qw4iqIR0uhTXGAhelQRhaZtKjyGkdBP6F4xqEGG1ArdW5@JDXKm6w0mEQN90FeiM203p4XR1Id77wZHHfk1gh0S1JgVWS2O2v9gfEzzYtUy@jUN@AuDpoGAmm19TBjsphvjwUWfFiJx4CP8atH8B)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.filter(e=>e=='b').length>s.filter(e=>e=='s').length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBbgMxCEX3OUV3Hi86F6icu9iUSagQP8JuK59@6kpVlCqKW7FA4j/gw1v@yJVcLu3Z8Mr7lvaajnXdRBv7wunIKYUS4qpsp3a@k@pV2glWobwqTkv4lHZ@Kg4iqIR4uBW3JRC8KAnCWi8qbQkhxofQv2AUgwirZbjVMhZPcaXiDicRAn3TRaAjHjfFl8PdhXhvkyPnfk1gU6JYlQwruTLbX@yPCe7smgdf@5QfAHg4yBjJxteUwU6KLt69l1ExIifuwr8G7V8)

Comment: How does this solution work..?

Comment: Ah yes, I had the same idea, but yours is shorter.